# Oracle DataAdapter Update method inserts only one row when updateBatchSize=0

Tags: oracle, ado.net, adapter

I am trying to implement batch insert in the Oracle database table using ado.net OracleDataAdapter class. I am following the below steps:

1. Create the DataTable object by specifying the column names
2. Next, populate the DataTable with DataRows

   ```
   foreach (var item in product)
       {
           //bulkUpdateHelper.AddEntity(item);

           var dataRow = _dataTable.NewRow();
           dataRow[1] = item.Description;
           dataRow[2] = item.Name;
           dataRow[3] = item.Price;
           dataRow[4] = item.Category;

           _dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
       }
   ```
3. I am creating the insert command and select command with the insert query and select queries
4. I added the insert parameter for each of the columns in insert SQL.
5. Then, I created the `OracleDataAdapter` object by specifying the select command.
6. I called the update method setting the `UpdateBatchSize=0`.

On calling the update, only one row gets inserted into the Database whereas datatable has more than one rows. Also, when I try to set the `UpdateBatchSize>0` I am getting object reference not found an error.

Please help if anyone has faced the same issue.

Thanks for the help and time.

I figured out the issue. After adding the datarow, I was calling AcceptChanges() method on data table instead of datarow.

Comment: Please check primary keys constraints of the table in oracle, may you have same unique key value in each row.

Comment: I have used sequence.nextval for unique key

Comment: Can you post insert SQL statement and code